# Can I remove #sql_ .MYD files?

Tags: mysql, myisam, temporary-tables, mysql-5.0

I found some old files in the mysql datadir:

```
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql     0 2012-10-09 09:39 #sql_263c_0.MYD
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  1.0K 2012-10-09 09:39 #sql_263c_0.MYI
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql     0 2012-10-09 09:40 #sql_263c_1.MYD
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  1.0K 2012-10-09 09:40 #sql_263c_1.MYI
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql     0 2012-10-09 09:40 #sql_263c_3.MYD
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  1.0K 2012-10-09 09:41 #sql_263c_3.MYI
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  338M 2012-08-21 15:54 #sql_3e03_0.MYD
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  1.0K 2012-08-21 15:52 #sql_3e03_0.MYI
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  694M 2012-08-21 15:54 #sql_3e03_12.MYD
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  1.0K 2012-08-21 15:46 #sql_3e03_12.MYI
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  756M 2012-08-21 15:54 #sql_3e03_13.MYD
```

I have no idea how does it created, maybe temp tables ? Is it possible to check the files still used by mysqld or can be remove ?

My version is: Server version: 5.0.45-log Source distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By all means, remove them. Those are just temporary tables mysqld had written to disk.

In all likelihood, mysqld probably crashed when those temp tables were made.

Look at the timestamps:

- Max is `2012-10-09`
- Min is `2012-08-21`

The sum of these files are over `1G`. They are just taking up room.

I know they are temp tables because

- MySQL uses MyISAM as the Storage Engine for Temp Tables
- Temp Tables have no `.frm`, which prohibit DB sessions from accessing them directly in SQL

You can remove the corresponding `.MYI` files as well. Those are the index file components of teach temporary MyISAM tables. They are never populated because temp tables are never indexed.